# Retornar HTML em uma API seria uma boa prática?Microsserviço?

Tags: api, microsserviços

Este é o cenário: Uma empresa vai oferecer informações sob o formato de imagens e caracteres e htmls-iframes (cupons, roupas, produtos) para que os seus clientes (lojas, atacadistas, varegistas, etc) insiram nos seus websites. Ou seja, além de dados existem algumas regras de negócios, imagens de produtos de cada cliente, (o cliente quer exibir o sabonete X de uma maneira e o cliente B quer que a imagem do sabonete X seja de outra maneira.)

A minha abordagem é a criação de uma api que vai oferecer os endpoints para os seus clientes.

A API será RESTful, por isso estava fazendo uma pesquisa nesse [post](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) para entender melhor sobre boas práticas de construção de APIs..

Aminha dúvida é em relação a operacionalização desse serviço. Onde colocar as regras de negócio? Dentro da API?

No meu entendimento a API, no fim das contas deveria trabalhar, somente como uma interface que oferece acesso ao banco de dados, servindo end-points para fazer as operações CRUD, e retornando respostas JSON, somente.

Mas os cleintes precisam de alguns objetos iframes, ou seja, precisam dos dados que restornam do banco de dados e mais alguns elementos HTML ou imagens.

Entao aqui está a minha dúvida. A API deveria retornar HTML? Isso é uma boa prática? Vai ser legal para a posterior manuntenção? Ou seja deveríamos seguir o caminho verde do desenho abaixo ou ir direto para a API (caminho laranja)?

Nesse caso o caminho verde é ser criado um serviço que iria consumir os endpoints da API e nele poderíamos inserir as regras de negócio e os HTMLs. Nesse cenário esse serviço (Microserviço?) não seria uma API mas estaria agindo como uma, pois para o cliente 1 ou 2 eles só precisariam desses end-points para ser usado no seus web sites.

Fiz esse desenho abaixo ara explicar melhor:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A API deveria retornar HTML? Isso é uma boa prática?

E porque não seria?

Se você está falando explicitamente a respeito de APIs REST, a resposta é provavelmente *não* porque você não estaria retornando objetos em algum tipo de envelope de dados (JSON, XML, etc.)

Porém se sua API possuir aspectos não-REST, nada lhe impede de retornar conteúdo `text-html` a partir de um dado *endpoint*.

Comment: Está correto, poderia retornar HTML e tbm JSON ou XML. Mas isso seria uma boa práitca? Ou seja estaria mandando as regras de negócio para dentro da API. Isso iria aumentar a complexidade e consequentemente aumentar a complexidade da manutenção tbm. Entáo seria uma melhor abordagem criar um micro serviço para guardar a API mais enxuta?

Comment: @zwitterion é possível argumentar que o contrário estaria acontecendo - complexidade (de implementação e manutenção) está sendo adicionada apenas para segregar a funcionalidade. A não ser que você esteja falando de uma API cujo papel seja apenas servir de *layer* de comunicação, *ela faz parte do negócio*.

Comment: ok.. entendi. Então o foco vai ser na funcionalidade. A complexidade vai sr uma consequência da escolha da função, e será algo inevitável.

Comment: @zwitterion Exatamente. No fim das contas, é uma escolha de design - manutenção será necessária de uma maneira ou de outra.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o caminho traçado de verde ficaria mais organizado. A API Rest retornaria apenas json para um serviço que customizaria a resposta renderizada (Html ou outro formato) para cada cliente, dessa forma a sua API Rest não dependeria do cliente em si. O Problema desse formato é que teria o custo da requisição HTTP (Custo de Rede) pois teria uma requisição a mais para devolver a resposta final para o cliente. Assim como aplicações MVC, a API pode devolver uma página já renderizada (HTML), porém esta prática está caindo em desuso para aplicações WEB, pois a API fica muito engessada e expecífica demais.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).